# Angular2 router, content changes, how to avoid routing and rebuilding page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an route that is a fairly heavy component, it's got youtube player and disqus comments.  I want to change the content (video) and get the url fixed up to the new video.  Routing to it, with the new UI rebuilds the page. I'd like to avoid that.

How do I use the angular2 router to fixup the url, without actually routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Angulars [Location](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/Location-class.html). In this way only the url gets updated, but the router is not navigating to it.

```
import {Location} from 'angular2/router';
 class Component {
  constructor(location: Location) {
    location.go('/foo');//Add your params here
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not all there.  I have another question that goes a bit further. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249207/angular2-routing-heavy-page-simulate-navigation