# Angular2 Routing, heavy page, simulate navigation

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I need to be some help on routing. Most of it works fine, including back and forward buttons in browser, as long as I am moving between different routes. But I have a heavyweight component (youtube player) (route) that I want to just change the content on `/route/:id` and avoid re-initializing the component. So I use the `Location.go(:id)` to fix up the url.

But now the back and forward buttons in the browser don't work correctly. I thought I could use `Location.subscribe` to hook the browser event, change the content OR navigate and move on. BUT.. the back and forward buttons aren't behaving. If I go back (to the `location.go()`) url, there's no forward. I can't go back twice.

I hope someone can give me a strategy here... I'm going in circles.
Seems like the `Location.go(:id)` just isn't taking care of business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement [CanReuse](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html) on your heavyweight component and return `true`, then the component instance will be kept and just re-added when you route back.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks. Although, the back and forward buttons aren't working exactly right, when I'm on the same route w/different ids. Will be digging into that more.

Comment: You shouldn't use `Location.go()`. Use instead `this.router.navigate...()` (requires that you inject the `Router` to your component/service (don't add ROUTER_PROVIDERS` to components though - only `bootstrap(...)`

Comment: Navigating to a different route (where only a parameter is different might prevent `canReuse` taking effect (haven't played to much with it myself). The router isn't considered to be feature-complete anyway. There are lots of discussions going on how to improve and how to proceed.

Comment: See also the ongoing discussion in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7784#issuecomment-202420812

Comment: Yes, I did discover that Location.go() was a dead end. As your suggest, I did go to `this.router.navigate(..)`, and as I said, it's almost there, but I think the angular implementation just isn't all there yet. The back/forward keys aren't exactly correct when re-using on same route, but the back/forward are perfect when navigating between different components.  Thanks for the link. ;)